# How do I use VBA to add the File Name into the Footer?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Here is what I have so far :)

What I am trying to do is add the filepath and the file name into the footer in the word document, that is being created from excel...

```
Function ReportTypeC()

Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim SrcePath As String
Dim FileName As String

FileName = ActiveDocument.FullName

SrcePath = "L:\TEST\Archive\unnamed.jpg"

Set wdApp = New Word.Application

With wdApp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate

    .Documents.Add
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    .ActiveDocument.Sections.Item(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary) _
        .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture (SrcePath)

    .ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary) _
    .PageNumbers.Add PageNumberAlignment:=wdAlignPageNumberLeft, FirstPage:=True

    'With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
        '.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "FileName"
    'End With
End With

End Function
```

Comment: There is no question in your question....

Comment: Is it not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?  What does it actually do or not do?

Comment: Remove the quotes around "FileName"

Comment: Rory, taking the quotes out doesn't fix the problem either.

Comment: Tim Williams, the Code is supposed to add the file name of the word document that is being produced into the footer.

Comment: You cannot add a filename to the footer when there is no name to the file. It just got created without a name `.Documents.Add`. If you still want to add it then replace `"FileName"` with `.ActiveDocument.Name`. It will have a footer of `Document1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your function for write document name in footer that you can extend for what your need.

```
Option Explicit

Function ReportTypeC()

Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True
wdApp.Documents.Add

ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
Selection.TypeText Text:=ThisWorkbook.Path & thisworkbook.Name & ".docx"
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument

appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & thisworkbook.Name & ".docx"
wdApp.ActiveDocument.Close
wdApp.Quit
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

If you need to have the *Word* document's name in the file, you have to save it first (and you have to give it a name).

```
Sub ReportTypeC()

  Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
  Dim wdDoc as Word.Document
  Dim SrcePath As String
  Dim FileName As String

  SrcePath = "L:\TEST\Archive\unnamed.jpg"

  With wdApp
      .Visible = True
      .Activate
      Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
  End With

  'Build your file path and file name here; I am using ThisWorkbook assuming we are exporting to the same directory as the workbook, and calling the exported document "mydocument.docx"
  FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "mydocument.docx"

  With wdDoc
    .SaveAs FileName:=FileName
    With .Sections(1)
        .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture SrcePath
        .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add PageNumberAlignment:=wdAlignPageNumberLeft, FirstPage:=True
        .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = FileName
    End With
    .Save
  End With

End Sub
```

If you need to have the *Excel* workbook's filepath / name in the file, then you only need to refer to the `ThisWorkbook` object and its `FullName` property.

```
Sub ReportTypeC()

    Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc as Word.Document
    Dim SrcePath As String

    SrcePath = "L:\TEST\Archive\unnamed.jpg"

    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
    End With

    With wdDoc
        With .Sections(1)
            .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture SrcePath
            .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add PageNumberAlignment:=wdAlignPageNumberLeft, FirstPage:=True
            .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        End With
        .Save
    End With

End Sub
```

Personally, however, rather than build the document from scratch every time I call the macro, I would create a template, open the document in ReadOnly mode, and use find and replace to replace any *dynamic* data. Example

```
Sub ReportTypeC()

    Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc as Word.Document
    Dim SrcePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wdRange as Word.Range
    Const TemplatePath as String = "L:\TEST\Archive\Report C template.docx" ' This template contains the text "{{ FileName }}" and "{{ SourceWorkbook }}" in the footer, which is to be replaced.

    SrcePath = "L:\TEST\Archive\unnamed.jpg"

    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(FileName:=TemplatePath, ReadOnly:=True)
    End With

    ' Exported file
    FileName = "L:\TEST\Archive\" & "Report C " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".docx" ' e.g. "Report C 2017-09-27.docx"

    With wdDoc
        With .Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
            ' If we are sure that the template contains "{{ SourceWorkbook }}"), we can work with the range directly
            FindRange(.Range, "{{ SourceWorkbook }}").Text = ThisWorkbook.FullName
            ' If we aren't sure whether the template contains "{{ FileName }}" we need to check there's a match, so it doesn't replace the whole footer range
            Set wdRange = FindRange(.Range, "{{ FileName }}")
            If wdRange.Text = "{{ FileName }}" Then wdRange.Text = FileName
        End With
        ' Save the file
        .SaveAs FileName:=FileName
    End With

End Sub

Function FindRange(ByRef rLook As Word.Range, ByVal strFind As String) As Word.Range ' returns the first range that is matched by the strFind string
    rLook.Find.Execute Findtext:=strFind, MatchCase:=True, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop, MatchWholeWord:=True
    Set FindRange = rLook
End Function
```